# Windows force UAC elevation for files if their names contain "update"?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, uac, elevated-privileges

I am using Windows 7 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I created simple project with one `MessageBox()` call in `WinMain()`. The name of the project is `"update"`, so name of EXE file is `update.exe`. I have turned off manifest generation in Linker settings. But when I try to start debugging in Visual Studio, it says that my application requires elevation.

I decided to start application by clicking on it in Windows Explorer, but it still requires administrator privileges. I renamed it to `update12345.exe` and to `12345update12345.exe`, but it still requires elevation.

But when I renamed it to `12345.exe`, it worked perfectly without requesting administrator privileges! I thought that Windows requires elevation for all files which name contains `"update"` substring. So, I took another file (`debugview.exe` from the SysInternals DebugView) and renamed it to `update.exe` - but it works without elevation.

What can be the reason for this strange behaviour?

Comment: You are not building your program correctly, it is missing a manifest that declares it aware of UAC.  That's pretty hard to do wrong with Visual Studio, fall in the pit of success by using a project template to get your project started.

Comment: I have always developed projects without manifest and they worked perfectly. My project is designed to run on any Windows system and it does not do anything that requires UAC. But trouble is in the file name: if it contains "update", it requires UAC, if not it starts and works perfectly.

Comment: Hmya, they work perfectly until you hit some kind of wall head-on.  Like this one.  You'll have more surprises when you do things like poking around in the registry and accessing files in forbidden places.  The presence of the manifest has no effect whatsoever on old Windows versions that don't know what they mean.

Comment: My program does not and will not write to forbidden directories and forbidden keys in registry. If I need this, of course, I can add manifest requesting administrator privileges, or I can run my self program with `runas` in `ShellExecuteEx()`. But there is not reason to do this for my program, it does not require high privileges at all. But I found the problem - Windows forces UAC elevation for all EXE files, containing "update", "install" and "setup" in their names for compability with old installers and updaters.

Comment: [Installer detection](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/C/D/8CD015BB-081B-49C5-A506-9C9B570B8DD2/InstallerDetection.pptx) (link points to a PowerPoint presentation).

Comment: No, the problem is that you force Windows to guess at the intent of the program by omitting the manifest.  No real idea how to inspire you to solve this problem the Smart Way.  Luckily it is not my job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app not contains a requestedExecutionLevel into its manifest, Installer Detection Technology, checks if its name includes "update", "install", etc, to detect if is an installer app.
This explains because your app requires UAC when is renamed to "*update*", and other app than has a manifest not.