# Why does my win32 program need elevation?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have a very simple program that is used for auto-updating. It checks for available versions on a server (HTTPS), downloads new updates and runs the (possibly updated) program. This is an old program that was written in Delphi 7. It seems that this program requires elevation (run as admin) under Windows 8 and Windows 10. This is a problem, because once the program is elevated, it also starts the updated program elevated, and that is very bad.

The program code is very simple, it only contains Indy components from the server ( TIdHTTP ), and ShellAPI to execute he downloaded program, some IniFiles and a progress bar.

So the question is this: how can I find out which API call requires elevation, and how do I replace it? Is there a debugger that can tell what API call (at what code address) requires elevation?

Comment: Do some debugging and work out where the program fails. You might want to add an app manifest so that virtualization does not interfere. Do you know how to debug?

Comment: When I copy the exe file to a Windows 7 machine, its icon shows up with the admin shield in it. I can see that it requires admin privileges before it is started. The program cannot be loaded as a normal user. So I think by the time I would start debugging, it would already be elevated. Then how can I tell what is causing this? I'm not sure how to create a manifest file - never done that.

Comment: Oh, and I don't how how to debug, especially not under windows 7. This is a simple program that uses win32 api only. I don't think I have debug tools for win 7/8/10.

Comment: Maybe it's got to do with the name of your program? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140051/windows-force-uac-elevation-for-files-if-their-names-contain-update

Comment: If you don't have any development tools then how are you going to change anything. Obviously you have development tools since you created the program in the first place. Debugging under Windows 7/8/10 is the same as under any other version of Windows. Delphi 7 runs fine. The name of your program could be significant. I do think that you will need to spend some time catching up with the changes that were introduced with Vista around 10 years (!!) ago.

Comment: OMG! Yes, the name of the program contains "update".  Can I overcome this problem by creating a manifest file? Would it be better to rename my program? (But I would have to do it on about 50 client compuers).

Comment: Adding a manifest would stop that particular compat shim. Why don't you spend some time learning about the issues from the documentation. Are you sure you want to make decisions when you know so little about the issues? Aren't you likely to make poor decisions when you are poorly informed?

Comment: I'll read the docs. Unfortunately, I need a solution in the next 2 hours. By the way, renaming the program to something else did not help. I also had to remove "update" text from the app properties (internal name, application name etc.) Then it started to work!

Comment: OK, well don't bother trying to understand it then, just try stuff at random and if it looks like it works, go with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not necessarily an API call that requires elevation. It could simply be the program name instead. Is it maybe called something like `somethingUPDATE.exe`? If so, then without a UAC manifest to specify elevation settings, [Installer Detection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628.aspx) will kick in and Windows will think the program is an installer and automatically display the UAC prompt for elevation.
(The same goes for file names containing `Install`, `Setup`, `Patch`, etc).

> Installer Detection Technology
>
> Installation programs are applications designed to deploy software, and most write to system directories and registry keys. These protected system locations are typically writeable only by an administrator user, which means that standard users do not have sufficient access to install programs. Windows Vista heuristically detects installation programs and requests administrator credentials or approval from the administrator user in order to run with access privileges. Windows Vista also heuristically detects updater and uninstallation programs. Note that a design goal of UAC is to prevent installations from being executed without the user's knowledge and consent since they write to protected areas of the file system and registry.
>
> Installer Detection only applies to:
>
> 1. 32 bit executables
> 2. Applications without a requestedExecutionLevel
> 3. Interactive processes running as a Standard User with LUA enabled
>
> Before a 32 bit process is created, the following attributes are checked to determine whether it is an installer:
>
> - Filename includes keywords like "install," "setup," "update," etc.
> - Keywords in the following Versioning Resource fields: Vendor, Company Name, Product Name, File Description, Original Filename, Internal Name, and Export Name.
> - Keywords in the side-by-side manifest embedded in the executable.
> - Keywords in specific StringTable entries linked in the executable.
> - Key attributes in the RC data linked in the executable.
> - Targeted sequences of bytes within the executable.
>
> Note
>
> The keywords and sequences of bytes were derived from common characteristics observed from various installer technologies.

This link might also be interesting:

[Using the SpecificNonInstaller Fix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638326.aspx)

Comment: It's not really fair that I get all the points and badges for this answer when Remy Lebau edited and improved it so much.

Answer (score 3):

Possible reasons are:

Your program is named using words like "setup", "installer", "updater" etc. Windows is looking for these both in the .exe name, version and other resources.

Your program attempts to write to HKLM or HKCR registry hives or the "Program Files" or "Windows\System" folders.

Avoiding to write to mentioned regstry hives and folders was recommended already for Windows XP, but not really enforced until Windows Vista.

You can read more about [User Account Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742497.aspx) and linked documents.

Comment: The filename is taken into account only if the program does not have a UAC manifest with a `requestedExecutionLevel` specified. The program code that writes to HKLM or HKCR will not trigger a UAC elevation prompt when the program is started, it will simply virtualize/fail the Registry access as needed at runtime.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for clarification