# How to determine if a program needs elevated rights?

Tags: delphi, winapi, elevation

Imagine the following scenario:

I have an exe-file "DoINeedAdmin.exe" somewhere and want to check if this program would require admin-rights to start it.

It would be okay trying to start it and determine it by some failure return value.

Since Windows can obviously do this by adding the admin-icon to the exe if it needs elevated rights, I hope it's possible programmatically too.

Comment: "*It would be okay trying to start it and determine it by some failure return value*" - then do so. If the target app requires elevation, and the caller is not elevated, `CreateProcess()` will fail with an `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED` error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, there is no sure way.

Windows will start program elevated if that is specified in its manifest. They will also start it elevated if program name contains [Setup, Install, Update, Patch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756960.aspx) (maybe more) (unless this is [disabled by a local policy or a manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11573444/4997)).

Other than that, application can also request elevation from the code. There's no way you can detect that in external program.

Comment: It would completely fine for me, if I just can determine the elevation state before the program starts. If the application decides to request elevation at runtime that's "not my problem".

Comment: But I see there is no know-it-all-function for elevation in the winapi.

Comment: For a Delphi sample of parsing the manifest of a exe file try this https://theroadtodelphi.com/2011/06/13/how-get-and-parse-a-manifest-of-an-external-application-using-delphi/

Comment: Quick note, automated elevation only happens on 32 bit systems:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37441521/1382345

Answer (score 4):

There is a undocumented function in shell32 (ordinal 865) that takes a LPCWSTR path and returns a non-zero BOOL if the path requires elevation. I don't know if this function checks external manifests though.

Comment: That sounds promising. I will check it out and let you know about the results.

Comment: It's not helpful to suggest undocumented functions. Next Windows version or even an update may change ordinal value or do something completely different and break your code.

Comment: @zett42 Fair point but this ordinal has been stable since it was added to Vista. If you feel unsafe you can always use the name (but undocumented) kernel32 function from the duplicate answer.

Comment: I don't even think that's any fair point. Once you mention it's undocumented, any one can make their fair decision about using or not using it.

Comment: @Sertac Why would you use an undocumented API if you can achieve the desired result using a documented API that doesn't make your program potentially incompatible with future Win versions? Citing OP: _It would be okay trying to start it and determine it by some failure return value._

Comment: I would use it because it explicitly and directly does what I want, instead of obtaining a result through consequences of indirect actions @zett. However why I would do something or not is quite irrelevant. The point is, I can't even decide to use it or not if I don't know about it.

Comment: @Sertac *You* may even be able to decide whether the risk is outweighted by the return in your particular case, but I don't think *anyone* coming to SO via Google search results will be able to do so. In contrary, handing out knowledge about undocumented API may do more harm than good because many people will use it without muching thinking, especially if it is the "accepted" answer. Knowledge is not useful if it isn't paired with the wisdom how to use it.

Comment: I'm not in any position to decide whom has the competence to have knowledge. I don't think anyone here does, @zett. What people does with knowledge is their concern. Of course you may choose to not to share possibly harmful knowledge. But I don't think you can criticize anyone who does.

Comment: @Sertac If it's my *opinion* that such knowledge can be harmful, it's valid that I downvote an answer sharing such knowledge. The downvote button has a tooltip that states "not useful", which perfectly fits something I see as harmful.

Comment: The function works perfectly fine for me. I know that it is never good to use possible unsupported function. I used it with warning commentary to replace as soon as we have a better replacement. Since it works for me but would not be right to accept it, I only upvoted and will accept gabr's answer instead. Thanks for your help though! :)

Answer (score 2):

In short: [Application Manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx). This is an XML file embedded into an executable, and of particluar interest there is the `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />` [tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Comment: Are there any standard functions to read this?

Comment: Also, there is more than this manifest embedded. Like external manifests and name conventions that cause elevated rights.

Comment: You also have to check for "highestAvailable" if the user is in a group that can elevate.